# How to set a specific height/width for all elements in a WPF grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom ListBox where each item has a Grid defined where I display boxes. I can set the widths to be the same length by using the SharedSizeGroup property. However, how do I share this property for all these items within the parent ListBox element?

I tried setting the property on the ListBox element also but this did not work.

```
<ListBox
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"...>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Box" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Box" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Box" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyA}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyB}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyC}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting property `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on `Grid`, set it on Listbox like this -

```
 <ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

and remove it from the `Grid`.

This will make `all` the `listboxItems` to `share the same size` instead for an individual item.